# relate the zeros of a function and the fact that it is not periodic

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

In an attempt to relate the zeros of a function and the fact that it is not periodic, the following question came to me:

> Given a non-constant function $f$, and the succession of the difference of two consecutive zeros (of all its zeros) is strictly increasing, then $f$ is not periodic.

This is true?

Comment: In the case the function has inifnite many zeros (so that such a sequence exists) the conclusion is valid because in the case of a periodic function the difference between consecutive zeros cannot exceed the period length. But this criterion appears to be quite useless in practice. Are there non-exotic examples for such a function at all that satisfy the premise ?

Comment: I do not think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that $f$ is a nonconstant real-valued function of a real variable with zeros $\ldots<x_{-1}<x_0<x_1<x_2<\ldots$ such that $|x_{i+2}-x_{i+1}|>|x_{i+1}-x_i|$ for all $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, then yes it is true that $f$ cannot be periodic.

Assuming that $f$ were periodic, we would either have *one* zero per period, and therefore successive zeros in successive periods (as with $\sin^2(0)=\sin^2(\pi)=\ldots$), or *multiple* successive zeros per period (as with $\sin0=\sin\pi$). In the former case, we must have $f(x_i)=f(x_i+P)=f(x_i+2P)=\ldots$ where $P$ is the fundamental period, which obviously has non-increasing differences. In the latter case, the differences within a period cannot increase, since they would have to fall back to the first, smallest of the differences at the start of the next period, and hence necessarily decrease (see, e.g., $\sin\cot x)$. On the other hand, if the differences within a period are all equal, they cannot be increasing. Therefore $f$ cannot be periodic.